# How to use only 1 template value for a function in a class which has 2 templates values

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a hashmap in c++. This is my class

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class HashMap {
public:
    unsigned int map_size = 100;
    V* values_arr = new V[map_size];
    int hash(std::string); //I want one hash function for std::string
    int hash(K); //Then another to be used for integral types

};
```

Now this is the function I expect to be called for the K (key) is a string

```
template <typename K, typename V>
int HashMap<std::string, V>::hash(std::string value) { //This line is where the error is
    std::cout << "You are hashing a string";

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the one I want to be used when the key in an integral

```
template <typename K, typename V>
int HashMap<K, V>::hash(K value) {
    std::cout << "You are hashing an an integral";

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to encode that logic by declaring the function like `HashMap<std::string, V>` I think that should work but I'm not positive. The error I get is (I commented the line it's on)

> Error C3860   template argument list following class template name must
>   list parameters in the order used in template parameter list  HashMap

Comment: Why don't you just do what [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) does, and template Hash and KeyEqual? Or at least use somthing akin to `std::hash<K>` and `std::equal_to<K>` as customisation points

Comment: @Caleth Thanks for the advice, any chance you would be able to point me in the right direction to figure out what that means and how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead take inspiration from `std::unordered_map`, and take your hash 
 (and key equality) as a template parameter.

```
template <typename K>
struct MyHash; // don't know how to hash arbitrary types

template <>
struct MyHash<std::string> {
    int operator()(std::string s) {
        std::cout << "You are hashing a string";
        return 0;
    }
}

template <>
struct MyHash<int> {
    int operator()(int i) {
        std::cout << "You are hashing an int";
        return i;
    }
}

template <typename K>
struct MyEqual { // do know how to compare arbitrary types for equality
    bool operator()(K lhs, K rhs) {
        return lhs == rhs;
    }
}

template <typename K, typename V, typename Hash = MyHash<K>, typename Equal = MyEqual<K>>
class HashMap {
private:
    Hash hasher;
    Equal comparer;
    unsigned int map_size = 100;
    V* values_arr = new V[map_size];
public:
    int hash(K key) { return hasher(key); } // calls Hash::operator()(K)
    bool equal(K lhs, K rhs) { return comparer(lhs, rhs); } // calls Equal::operator()(K, K)
    // ... other members
};
```

Then, as an extension, you can do things like

```
struct CaseInsensitiveStringHash : private MyHash<std::string> {
    int operator()(std::string s) { return MyHash::operator()(s.to_lower()); }
}

struct CaseInsensitiveStringEqual : private MyEqual<std::string> {
    bool operator()(std::string lhs, std::string rhs) { 
        return MyEqual::operator()(lhs.to_lower(), rhs.to_lower()); 
    }
}

template <typename V>
using CaseInsensitiveStringMap = HashMap<std::string, V, CaseInsensitiveStringHash, CaseInsensitiveStringEqual>;
```

Comment: Thanks. this is the elegant solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

```
int string_hash(std::string value) {
    std::cout << "You are hashing a string";

    return 0;
}

template <typename V>
class HashMapBase {
public:
    unsigned int map_size = 100;
    V* values_arr = new V[map_size];
};

template <typename K, typename V>
class HashMap : public HashMapBase<V> {
public:
    int hash(std::string); //I want one hash function for std::string
    int hash(K); //Then another to be used for integral types

};

template <typename K, typename V>
int HashMap<K, V>::hash(std::string value) {
    return string_hash(value);
}

template <typename K, typename V>
int HashMap<K, V>::hash(K value) {
    std::cout << "You are hashing an an integral";

    return 0;
}

template <typename V>
class HashMap<std::string, V> : public HashMapBase<V> {
public:
    int hash(std::string);

};

template <typename V>
int HashMap<std::string, V>::hash(std::string value) {
    return string_hash(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried that on my own previously. The error I get (and still do) is
Error C2535 'int HashMap<std::string,int>::hash(std::string)': member function already defined or declared

Comment: Visual studio 2017, cl.exe shows `Version 19.10.25019 for x64`

Comment: So for HashMap<std::string,int> you want 2 different hash implementations?

Comment: I just want one function for HashMap<string, anything> and another for HashMap<anything, anything>. Obviously you can't hash a string the same way you would hash an integer/float/double/etc @lllShamanlll

Comment: Thanks again, it compiles when I use it with a string but doesn't when I use it with an integer, trying to fix it now

Comment: True, missed public modifier